# Show Highcharts series.name outside of chart margin

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I'm currently customising a Highcharts stacked column chart, I'm returning the series name and data percentage next to the stacked columns.

I've got this working fine using:

`plotOptions: {column: {dataLabels: {formatter: function () {return this.series.name + ' ' + this.y + '%'
                       } } } }`

The problem I'm facing is that I want my chart to be fairly narrow and reducing the width means that the series name & percent are cut off some of the series labels if they are too wide.

Is there a way to return the series labels outside of the chart?

This is what I'm trying to create:

[image: This is what I'm trying to create]

This is currently what I've got:

[image: This is currently what I've got]

I can make the chart wider and the labels will all show but this isn't ideal - any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using:

`dataLabels: {crop: false,
                        overflow: 'none',}`